# Refreshing Listview is not working when going back to the app

Tags: android, listview

I have an app with some tabs and every activity is a ListView with the same CursorAdapter bind to it.
Switching between tabs, everything is working, but when I go to the Launcher Menu and switch back to the activity,I have a blank list! Switching again between tab, every list is shown in the right way.

I used this code:

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!(myDBHelper.CheckIfIsOpen())) { myDBHelper.open();}
        if (myCarboCursor.isClosed()) { myCarboCursor = myDBHelper.getAllAlimentiByType("C");}
        myCarboCursor.requery();
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I think you have to call your activity again(using Intent) when you came back from Launcher Menu.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it! When I come back from other tabs I see that this_Activity.onResume() is called, the same when I come back from the Launcher. How I am supposed to change the behaviour ?